# How to retrieve items from a django queryset?

Tags: python, django, view, model, django-queryset

I'm trying to get the video element in a queryset but am having trouble retrieving it.

```
user_channel = Everything.objects.filter(profile = request.user, playlist = 'Channel')
print user_channel[0] #returns the first result without error   
print user_channel[0]['video'] #returns error
```

Models.py:

```
class Everything(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User)
    playlist = models.CharField('Playlist', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    platform = models.CharField('Platform', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.CharField('VideoID', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    video_title = models.CharField('Title of Video', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.profile, self.playlist, self.platform, self.video, self.video_title)
```

Comment: Did you try `user_channel[0].video`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_channel[0]` is not a dictionary. Use

```
user_channel[0].video
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this you get list of videos based on filter

```
user_channel = Everything.objects.filter(profile = request.user, playlist = 'Channel')
video = [x.video for x in user_channel]
print video/print video[0]
```